# How to filter DataFrame by any string column matching any regex pattern in a list?

Tags: python, python-polars

String columns can be selected with:

```python
df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8))
```

and a Dataframe's rows can be filtered with a regex pattern for a single column, with something like:

```python
df.filter(pl.col("feature").str.contains("dangerous"))
```

How can a DataFrame be filtered with a list of regex patterns that could appear in any string column?  I.e., if any string in a row matches any regex pattern, then keep that entire row, discard the rest.

**EDIT 1**

Here's a generated `df` and `patterns` to test functionality and performance.

```python
import random
from faker import Faker
import polars as pl

random.seed(42)
Faker.seed(42)

faker = Faker()

df_len = 10000

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("a", [random.randint(0, 511) for _ in range(df_len)]).cast(pl.Binary),
        pl.Series("b", [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(df_len)]).cast(pl.Boolean),
        pl.Series("c", faker.sentences(df_len), pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("d", [random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(df_len)], pl.UInt8),
        pl.Series("e", faker.words(df_len), pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series(
            "f",
            [random.randint(0, 255) * random.TWOPI for _ in range(df_len)],
            pl.Float32,
        ),
        pl.Series("g", faker.words(df_len), pl.Utf8),
    ]
)

patterns = [r"(?i)dangerous", r"always", r"(?i)prevent"]
```

`print(df)` yields:

```
shape: (10000, 7)
┌───────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬─────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ a             ┆ b     ┆ c                                   ┆ d   ┆ e         ┆ f          ┆ g        │
│ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---                                 ┆ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ binary        ┆ bool  ┆ str                                 ┆ u8  ┆ str       ┆ f32        ┆ str      │
╞═══════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪═════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Agent every development say.        ┆ 164 ┆ let       ┆ 980.17688  ┆ yard     │
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ Beautiful instead ahead despite ... ┆ 210 ┆ reach     ┆ 458.672516 ┆ son      │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Information last everything than... ┆ 230 ┆ arm       ┆ 50.265484  ┆ standard │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Choice whatever from behavior be... ┆ 29  ┆ operation ┆ 929.911438 ┆ final    │
│ ...           ┆ ...   ┆ ...                                 ┆ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...        ┆ ...      │
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ Building sign recently avoid upo... ┆ 132 ┆ practice  ┆ 282.743347 ┆ big      │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Paper will board.                   ┆ 72  ┆ similar   ┆ 376.991119 ┆ just     │
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ Technology money worker spring m... ┆ 140 ┆ sign      ┆ 94.24778   ┆ audience │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ A third traditional ago.            ┆ 40  ┆ available ┆ 615.752136 ┆ always   │
└───────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴─────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

**EDIT 2**

Using [@jqurious's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470301/1409374) (the fastest so far), the correct output of `df.filter(pl.any(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.contains(regex)))` is:

```
shape: (146, 7)
┌───────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ a             ┆ b     ┆ c                                   ┆ d   ┆ e         ┆ f           ┆ g        │
│ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---                                 ┆ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ binary        ┆ bool  ┆ str                                 ┆ u8  ┆ str       ┆ f32         ┆ str      │
╞═══════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪═════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ During prevent accept seem show ... ┆ 137 ┆ various   ┆ 471.238892  ┆ customer │
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ Ball always it focus economy bef... ┆ 179 ┆ key       ┆ 471.238892  ┆ guy      │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Admit attack energy always.         ┆ 175 ┆ purpose   ┆ 1281.769775 ┆ wonder   │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Beyond prevent entire staff.        ┆ 242 ┆ hair      ┆ 904.778687  ┆ around   │
│ ...           ┆ ...   ┆ ...                                 ┆ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...         ┆ ...      │
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ Your sure piece simple always so... ┆ 247 ┆ recently  ┆ 1055.575073 ┆ laugh    │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ Difference all machine let charg... ┆ 178 ┆ former    ┆ 1061.858276 ┆ always   │
│ [binary data] ┆ true  ┆ Morning carry event tell prevent... ┆ 3   ┆ entire    ┆ 1432.566284 ┆ hit      │
│ [binary data] ┆ false ┆ A third traditional ago.            ┆ 40  ┆ available ┆ 615.752136  ┆ always   │
└───────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Edited question and added generated `df` and `patterns`.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity ... and correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the list into a single regex.

```
regex = "|".join(
   f"(?:{pattern})" for pattern in 
   sorted(patterns, key=len, reverse=True)
)
```

```
df.filter(pl.any(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.contains(regex)))
```

Comment: This works!  On my machine, using my sample `df` and `patterns`, `%timeit df.filter(pl.any(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.contains(regex)))` produces `2.36 ms ± 61.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`.

Comment: You could also use `df.filter(pl.any(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.contains(pattern) for pattern in patterns))` instead of building a single regex. It should be "slower" - but you may be interested in adding it to your benchmark.

Comment: On my machine, `%timeit df.filter(pl.any(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.contains(pattern) for pattern in patterns))` produces `2.39 ms ± 95.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`.  Yeah it's ever so slightly slower.

Comment: I was wondering why you `sorted` the `patterns` first, so I also benchmarked `reverse=False` and it was faster: `2.18 ms ± 73.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`.  Any idea why?

Comment: I guess it's not strictly required for matching. When building a single regex that is used in a substitution, you want the longer patterns first incase a shorter pattern intersects e.g. `re.sub(r"word|wordcloud", "", "My wordcloud")` "doesn't work" - so it's just habit that I always sort them.

Comment: I'm assuming `polars` _under-the-hood_ is using `rust`'s regex stuff.  Is it possible, or would it make sense, to somehow "lazy parallelize" the individual patterns? ... or is `rust` doing that already?  ... or is that what `... for pattern in patterns` is doing?  How can we know what is parallelized?

Comment: Yes, that's already happening. It's running 3 expressions in this case: `print([pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.contains(pattern) for pattern in patterns])`

Answer (score 1):

To check regex patterns for each string column, you can use `.fold()` method

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": ["foo", "fo", "foa"],
    "b": ["foa", "fo", "foo"]
})

df.filter(
    pl.fold(acc=pl.lit(False),
            f=lambda acc, col: acc | col.str.contains("foo"),
            exprs=pl.col(pl.Utf8))
)
```

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ foo ┆ foa │
│ foa ┆ foo │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Another way to do it - concat all string columns into a single one and then apply regex expressions:

```py
df.filter(
    pl.concat_str(pl.col(pl.Utf8)).str.contains("foo")
)
```

Comment: Both of your `df.filter(...` examples work!  On my machine, using my sample `df` and `patterns` joined as in [@jqurious's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470301/1409374), `%timeit df.filter(pl.fold(...` produces `3.97 ms ± 51.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` and `%timeit df.filter(pl.concat_str(...` produces `2.64 ms ± 62.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`.